# Client OAuth Settings are not showing in my app advance settings in facebook login

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am working and actually creating a login through facebook system and in order to redirect it, i am not getting any client OAuth settings in advance setting options while creating the app.

Answer (score 51):

1) Go to Dashboard
2) At bottom of left column `Product Settings` -> click `+Add Product`
3) Add `facebook Login`.
4) It will appear in the left column - click it there.
5) And You will find **Client OAuth Login** on the right.

Comment: ya got it.I had the same problem

Comment: What an awkward UX! Could they make the setting any harder to find?